# I can't see the images of the web debug toolbar

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I can't see the images of the web debug toolbar.

I'm getting this error for example:

> GET
>   http://francesca.localhost/web/sf/sf_web_debug/images/close.png
>   404 (Not Found)

If I request http://francesca.localhost/sf/sf_web_debug/images/close.png it works ok (the image is showed).

This is my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80> 
   ServerName francesca.localhost 
   ServerAlias francesca.com 
   DocumentRoot /home/me/programacion/francesca 

   <Directory /home/me/programacion/francesca/web> 
      AllowOverride All 
      Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
      Allow from All 
   </Directory> 


   Alias /sf /home/me/programacion/francesca/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf 
   <Directory "/home/me/programacion/francesca/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf"> 
    AllowOverride All 
    Allow from All 
   </Directory> 

</VirtualHost>
```

sf 1.4

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have DocumentRoot /home/me/programacion/francesca/**web**